# Is it legal for a school to ask students to scan their signature and send it?

Tags: canada, signature

We are about 40 students at the end of college in Quebec, Canada and we are about to have an internship for our last semester. During our meeting today, the teachers talked about lots of things including a document that must be signed by the company, the teachers and the student.

Since they don't want to spend time asking every of 40 students signing that document, they are asking us to sign and scan our signature to send it to them via a private google drive folder. Its been confirmed that we will have access to that document before our signature gets appended on it.

Is it legal for the school do to that?

Comment: If you agree to the contract, it's totally legitimate, since  the signature just records your assent. It's a bit of an odd way to do it, though, for just 40 people who are presumably in the same place and same time at some point.

Comment: Is there any reason you would think that it is not legal to do that? No reason that it would be illegal obviously comes to mind.

Comment: A more "normal" way to do that would be to have each student sign a copy of the document and scan and send THAT, resulting in a completed document signed "in multiple parts".  Doing it that way limits the use of your scanned signatures in unauthorized ways (e.g., on other documents).